# How to make your own glazed cherries?

Tags: glaze, cherries

Glazed/candied cherries, the sort that sits nicely on top of a sundae. I don't like the look of the packaged ones in my local supermarket, is there an easy way to create my own?

Also, how to best pit these cherries without compromising their structural integrity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making maraschino cherries is a bit involved... basically, you brine them and then flavor them. To keep them for a long time, you'll also need to can them.

[Here's](http://www.recipesource.com/side-dishes/condiments/01/rec0102.html) a great recipe for making the cherries, and [here's](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_02/cherry_sweet_topping.html) instructions for canning.

The canning instructions are specifically for cherry topping, but you would use the same boiling-water canner process for maraschino cherries in their syrup.

To pit the cherries, I'd advise purchasing a cherry pitter (yes, there's actually a device for this) if you're going to be doing this very much.